# Как исправить ошибку - индексы не должны быть str, в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, циклы, машинное-обучение

Я загрузил [Данные](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1m457nzokjz3q86/gbm-data.csv?dl=0) и обозначил переменные, а затем преобразовал выборку в массив.

```
 df1 = pd.read_csv('gbm-data.csv')
 Y = df1['Activity']
 X = df1.drop(['Activity'], axis=1)
 df2 = df1.values`
```

После разделения данных, на обучающую и тестовую выборки:

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, Y1, test_size=0.8, random_state=241`

Мне необходимо обучить `GradientBoostingClassifier` с параметрами `n_estimators=250`, `verbose=True`, `random_state=241` и для каждого значения `learning_rate` из списка `[1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]` выполнить следующее:

1. Используйте метод `staged_decision_function` для предсказания качества
   на обучающей и тестовой выборке на каждой итерации.
2. Преобразуйте полученное предсказание с помощью сигмоидной функции 
   по формуле 1 / (1 + e^{−y_pred}), где `y_pred` — предсказанное значение.
3. Вычислите и постройте график значений `log-loss` (которую можно
   посчитать с помощью функции `sklearn.metrics.log_loss`) на обучающей
   и тестовой выборках, а также найдите минимальное значение метрики и 
   номер итерации, на которой оно достигается.

Я написал следующий адаптированный под для построения моих моделей и сохранения результатов их вычисления:

```
common_args = {'verbose': True, 'n_estimators': 250,'random_state': 241}
models = [('first', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=1, **common_args)),
          ('second', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.5, **common_args)),
          ('third', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.3, **common_args)),
          ('forth', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.2, **common_args)),
          ('fifth', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, **common_args)),
         ]
stage_preds = []
final_preds = []
y_pred = []
Lloss = []
sigmaYpred = []
for mname, m in models:
    m.fit(X_train, y_train)
    stage_preds[mname] = {'X_train': list(m.staged_decision_function(X_train)),  'X_test': list(m.staged_decision_function(X_test))}
    y_pred[mname] = {'X_test': m.predict_proba(X_test)}
    sigmaYpred[mname] = 1 / (1 + np.exp((-1)*y_pred))
    Lloss[mname] = {'y_train': list(log_loss(y_train, sigmaYpred[mname])),  'y_test': list(log_loss(y_test, sigmaYpred[mname]))}
```

Но получаю постоянно эту ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 15, in 
>       stage_preds[mname] = {'X_train': list(m.staged_decision_function(X_train)),  'X_test':
>   list(m.staged_decision_function(X_test))} TypeError: list indices must
>   be integers or slices, not str

В как её исправить чтобы результаты могли сохраняться нормально?

P.S.: Исправив `stage_preds` и сделав ее словарём:

```
stage_preds = dict()
```

Появляется та же ошибка но с `y_pred[mname]`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 17, in 
>      y_pred[mname] = {'X_test': m.predict_proba(X_test)}
>   TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Если эту переменную задать как словарь тоже то невозможно будет произвести вычисления сигмы (`sigmaYpred[mname]`) так как пайтон не будет знать как взаимодействовать со словарём и числами.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему коду, вам нужно сделать `stage_preds` словарем:

```
models = [('first', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=1, **common_args)),
          ('second', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.5, **common_args)),
          ('third', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.3, **common_args)),
          ('forth', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.2, **common_args)),
          ('fifth', GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, **common_args)),
         ]

stage_preds = dict()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но ошибка та же появляется только теперь с переменной `y_pred`

Comment: Та переменная, мой невнимательный друг, тоже является списком :) `[]` / `list()` -- списки, у них доступ осуществляется по целочисленным индексам, начиная с 0 и до `<размер списка - 1>`. Также, в список добавляются элементы через метод append, а не через оператор `[]`, этот оператор нужен для получения и изменения элемента по индексу. Словарь -- `{}` / `dict()` в качестве ключа могут иметь любой тип, например, строки, и добавление новых элементов осуществлимо через определенный метод и через оператор `[]`